# Best approximation for a closed set in a finite dimensional normed space

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

First of all I'd like to mention that it is a part of my home work so I'd like if you won't give the answer itself, but try to guide me into it. I've been losing my mind for the last couple of hours because I couldn't solve it on my own.

The question is as follows:

> Assume that $X$ is a finite dimensional normed space, and $C$ is a closed nonempty subset (not necessarily a subspace) of $X$. Assume that there is $y\in C$ that $\|y\|=\inf\{\|x\| : x\in C\}$. Prove that for every $x\in X$ there is  $c\in C$ that $d(x,c)=d(x,C)$.

I obviously tried to play a little with sequences $(y_n)$ and $(x_n)$ in $C$ that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x_n\|=d(x,C)\quad \text{ and }\quad\lim_{n\to \infty}\|y_n\|=\|y\|,$$ but I had no luck.

I would love help. I truely lost my mind with this question, and I bet it is not even that hard at all...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that if $X$ is finite-dimensional then the norm of $X$ is a closed map (this fails in infinite dimensions). Indeed, let $C$ be a closed set in $X$ and take $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $C$ such that $\|w_n\|\to t$ as $n\to \infty$. Then the sequence $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded, hence it contains a convergent subsequence $(w_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ with limit $w$, say. Consequently, $t=\|w\|$.

Take $x\in X$ and choose a sequence $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $C$ so that $\|x-u_n\| \to d(x, C)$ as $n\to \infty$. Choose now a convergent subsequence $(x-u_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ and you are done. Consequently, $(u_{n_k})_{k=1}\infty$ converges too; let $u$ be its limit. As $C$ is closed, $u\in C$ and we are done. $\square$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow.
1) it looks a little wierd because you didn't use the main claim, which is the existence of $y\in C$ that $||y||=inf\{||x||:x\in C\}$.
2) $(x-u_{n_k})$ isn't in $C$ so I don't know that it's limit is in $C$.

Comment: Note that since $(x-u_{n_k})$ converges, so does $(u_{n_k})$. However $u_{n_k}$ are in $C$ and $C$ is closed, so the limit is in $C$. 

Your assumption 1) is unnecessary.

Comment: It took me some time to make sure I'm cool with it. It's actually perfect and very elegant, thanks!